# Как сформировать строку необходимой длины

Tags: java, строки

Код работает, делал несколько вариантов, но все по размеру они очень громоздкие и не нравятся из-за этого. Как можно сформировать строку такой длины, чтобы была по размеру как строка.

Нужно, чтобы в результате выглядело вот так, а текст подставлялся абсолютно любой:

```
---------------------------
Перевели из отдела в отдел
---------------------------
```

Либо же

```
------
Привет
------
```

Код:

```
public static void systemMessage(String message) {
    List<String> line  = new ArrayList<>();
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= message.length()) {
        line.add("-");
        i++;
    }
    for (String minus : line) {
        System.out.print(minus);
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(message);
    for (String minus : line) {
        System.out.print(minus);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: У вас размер `line` больше на 1 символ, так что размер не одинаковый

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так посмотрите

```
String message = "Перевели из отдела в отдел";
System.out.println("-".repeat(message.length()));
System.out.println(message);
System.out.println("-".repeat(message.length()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще один вариант:

```
   public static void systemMessage(String message) {
        String separator = IntStream.range(0, message.length())
                .mapToObj(obj -> "-")
                .collect(Collectors.joining(""));

        System.out.println(separator + "\n" + message + "\n" + separator);
    }
```